# Converting an angle to "turns" value for AnimatedRotation widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an angle `qiblahDirection.qiblah * (math.pi / 180) * -1` that represents the rotation angle in degrees. I want to use the AnimatedRotation widget in Flutter to animate the rotation based on this angle. However, the AnimatedRotation widget uses a "turns" value instead of degrees. How can I convert this angle into a suitable "turns" value for the AnimatedRotation widget?

I've tried scaling the angle by dividing it by 180.0, but it doesn't seem to produce the expected rotation. Can someone provide guidance on how to correctly convert the angle to a "turns" value for the AnimatedRotation widget?

I want to turn this widget

```
Transform.rotate(
  angle: (qiblahDirection.qiblah* (pi / 180) * -1),
  child: Image.asset(
    "assets/images/needle.png",
    fit: BoxFit.fill,
  ),
),
```

to this widget

```
AnimatedRotation(
  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
  turns: (qiblahDirection.qiblah / 180.0 ?? 0) / 360,
  child: Image.asset(
    "assets/images/needle.png",
    fit: BoxFit.fill,
  ),
),
```

Any help or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Divide by 360 instead of 180?  And make sure that your input angle isn't greater than 360 or less than 0?

Comment: Your output should be in the range [0,1].  If you want to turn backwards, start from `1` and move toward `0`

Comment: @Cullub did u mean (qiblahDirection.qiblah / 360 ?? 0) / 360,

Comment: I'm not sure what all your variables are/do, but to get from an angle to a rotation you should generally do `myRotation = myAngle / 360`, provided `myAngle` starts out in the range [0,360].  (If that isn't true, do math on your `myAngle` variable first to make that true.)

Comment: "Can someone provide guidance on how to correctly convert the angle to a "turns" value for the AnimatedRotation widget?" - check https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedRotation/turns.html

Comment: @Cullub what i'm doing is a compass for qiblah. so in transform.rotate angle it works. but when i use turns it doesn't calculate correctly so i wanna convert the angle to turns